# Career gaps and not worked for more than 1 to 1.5 years in any company. Plus I need to switch career

Tags: career-switch, employment-gaps

I really need help on this. My resume has some around 2 career breaks, also, I have around 6years work experience in 4 companies. I have seen a couple of HRs and managers, question my stability. How do I get through this?

Comment: Did you switch companies because you wanted higher salary and better benefits ? Or, were you let go because your former companies wanted to cut costs ? Or, did they let you go because your job performances did not meet their requirements? --- When you have job interviews with the new companies, did they ask you the reasons you left your former employers ?

Answer (score 8):

You need to convince the hiring manager that you won't be someone who is going to leave after a year; the only way you can do that is to explain why those career breaks and switches happened. That will be a lot easier if they are "took career break to care for ailing parent" than if they are "decided to go travelling"; similarly, people will be more likely to understand "got laid off because of COVID" rather than "switched company because new one uses <insert name of latest hype technology here>". In case it's not obvious - the "good" reasons there are ones which are unlikely to occur again.

If you do have "bad" reasons for the multiple breaks/changes, try as hard as you can when you do get a job to stick at it.

Aside: you would also explain why you "need" to switch career.

Comment: @Neyha, This answer is right.  If you did not like your old career and therefore did not do a good job in the past, and had to leave the old jobs, then you can tell the new hiring managers that your new career fits you better because you REALLY love it, and you won't leave your new jobs or new career now (because you REALLY REALLY love your new career).